# Obj-C: UIView from Nib being released between willAppear and didAppear

Tags: objective-c, uiview, crash, nib, retain

I have a view in a nib, which is linked to a property in my viewcontroller with the following line:

```
@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *otherView;
```

It is unsafe_unretained because we are targeting ios 4 devices, but using ARC.

We are getting a crash because the otherView is being deallocated when we are trying to show it, and I'm not too sure why.  I've put a breakpoint in viewWillAppear, and if I do "po otherView" in the debugger, i get:

```
<UIView: 0x6fcc880; frame = (0 0; 320 460); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x6fcc8b0>>
```

I checked it at the end of the viewWillAppear method, and it is still there too.  But then if I put a breakpoint at the beginning of viewDidAppear, I get:

```
0x6fcc880 does not appear to point to a valid object.
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction with this?  If I change the property declaration to 'Strong', then this issue doesn't occur, and I understand that by changing it to Strong that I am retaining it (and therefore preventing it from being deallocated), but I don't think I should need to do this?

Regards,
Nick

Comment: Where else is the view being retained?  If no where else, then you need to retain it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a retained property (`strong` | `retain`) on any topLevel objects from a xib.

[image]

In this example above `view1` would need to have a retained property. `view2` does not require a retained property but I generally just leave it as retained anyway as it does not hurt anything.

---

#### Why is the retain not required?

`view2` does not require a retained property because it is owned by `view1` and any references you have`are arbitrary references between objects that do not imply ownership.` (Apple, [Resource Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html)). But it doesn't hurt to have a retained property either, just make sure to call `self.view2 = nil` in `viewDidUnload`

Comment: Ah ha! I did not know this. Based on this, can I also make the assumption that the view controller retains whatever you assign as its view? Many thanks

Comment: It's never wise to assume things but I can imagine this would be pretty good guess